# Magneto 2.x Questions | Get Shipping Methods Clears Credit Card Data

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, coupon-codes

We completed our 1.x to 2.x upgrade and we are having some lingering issues.
Magento ver. 2.3.5

**Our shipping method is always free shipping**

When we are taking phone orders and we go to Sales >>Orders >> new we have to click get shipping methods and it deletes credit card data. For now we are trying to remember not to enter credit card data until this is entered, but curious if there is a way to preload this or stop it from clearing data.

**Purchase Order** We do not accept that via online orders but in 1.x we were able to have it available for us manually on phone orders. Is there a way to get a payment method to appear for manual orders but not to the public

*** Address Verification***

It appears you have to use the sales tax vendor they have listed to get address verification. Is there an easy affordable way to get address verification?

**Coupon Codes**

Is there a setting to keep coupon codes from applying to sale prices? We have a hack right now. Created an invisible category SALE, put sale items in that category and manually exclude that category from every coupon code individually

Thanks

Justin Krauss